# Error: NAND: could not write file /hd2/android-sdk-linux_86/add-ons/google_apis-7_r01/images//system.img, File exists

Tags: android-emulator

I am new comer to Android development.
Installed fresh Eclipse (Ganymede), Android android-sdk-linux_86.
Tried HelloWorld program.

Compiles OK.

An AVD "my1" created for API level 7.

The Emulator does not start, giving an error:
[2010-03-11 16:49:49 - Emulator] NAND: could not write file /hd2/android-sdk-linux_86/add-ons/google_apis-7_r01/images//system.img, File exists

Perplexed. Help requested.

Answer (score 21):

Try to check the free space on your hard drive

Comment: Wow, I also had very little free space on a disc and making few hundreds MB free really worked! That's an awfully unhelpful error message emulator gives.

Comment: 150 GB here, probably another problem.